# Alternative to HttpContext.Current.Items in ASP.NET Web Api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, nlog, httpcontext

is there a non- System.Web/HttpContext alternative to HttpContext.Current.Items, a per-request data storage?

I want to save information of a request, save them and read the values from my logger (NLog). I found a good place to do this is the DefaultHttpControllerActivator/IHttpControllerActivator.

This way the log messages should always look the same and the developer doesn't have much influence on the format or information provided.

**Edit**: After some more research i found this:
[How can we create a callcontext for async .net methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26013358/how-can-we-create-a-callcontext-for-async-net-methods)
I hope using the logical call context with immutable collections will work as expected.

Comment: Why did you require an alternative? Does Web Api not have an HttpContext.Current or an Items property on it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`HttpRequestMessage.Properties` is an `IDictionary<string, Object>` collection for storing arbitrary per-request data. Within a controller action this is readily available as `Request.Properties` property on the base `ApiController` class.

Not sure how exactly you're planning on using this for logging, but you may also want to look into writing a Logging `DelegatingHandler`